# In performance aspect which one is best if or switch or ternary?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP.

In PHP there are 3 Conditional structures

1. IF     2.SWITCH            3. TERNARY

Among these 3 which one is best to improve program performance ?

Please tell me in which conditions we need to preference IF or SWITCH or TERNARY    and why ?

How it increases performance based on condition and what is its execution time ?

Comment: The speed difference is going to be so minor in any case that unless you're processing millions and millions of data points in a single run it's not going to make any real difference.  You're basically talking about a [tag:micro-optimization], and premature optimization.

Comment: I agree with @GordonM and Ashwani here. The conditional is not going to be your performance problem if you get any. Code readability is far more important.

Answer (score 3):

There is no performance issue of using any. 
It depends on situation, which to use.
use ternary operator if condition is not very complex

LIKE :-

```
$num = $num == 1?'yes':'no'
```

Its better to use ternary operator to reduce the code size but for more complex conditions, it can become confusing so, use if

Switch should use when condition is same for most of case.
Like

```
if($num == 1 || $num == 2 || $num == 3 || $num == 5 || $num == 7 || $num == 11 ) {
    // do something
}
```

at this situation if should replace by switch, as it make code cleaner

Comment: In your last case I'd say that populating an array with the values you're interested in and using in_array would be a nicer option.  `if (in_array ($num, [1,2,3,5,7,11])) { /* do something */ }`  It's more readable, and more compact

Comment: Yes that is good point. I think it will be good to use in_array() over switch in this case. As using any will make minor difference in execution time.

Answer (score -1):

I did a small test and it would seem that the ternary operator is always a bit slower than the regular if statement. The difference is very small, so in the grand scheme of things it should impact your application performance much.

```
// small data
$data['test'] = 1;
$start = microtime();
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
  if (true) {
    $tmp = $data['test'];
  }
}
microtime() - $start; // 0.529772

$start = microtime();
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
  $tmp = true ? $data['test'] : false;
}
microtime() - $start; // 0.591775

// for 'large' data
$data['test'] = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
  $data['test'][] = $i;
}
$start = microtime();
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
  if (true) {
    $tmp = $data['test'];
  }
}
microtime() - $start; // 0.181477

$start = microtime();
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
  $tmp = true ? $data['test'] : false;
}
microtime() - $start; // 0.277483
```

Comment: This isn't a valid answer.. You wrote 7 words and gave a link to a 3rd party site that may not exist next week, and wouldn't provide any value to anyone.

Comment: My bad, I am quite new to this site, I will update my answer.